# Convert SQL query to access query

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I have used below query to update records in SQL. I have to do same thing in MS-ACCESS too. Here is the `SQL` query I used and worked

```
update Table1
SET Table1.a = Table2.b 
from  Table1
inner join Table2 on Table1.c = Table2.d 
where Table1.a = 0
```

In MS_ACCESS it is giving me syntax error (`missing operator`) in query expression Table2.b from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.c = Table2.d where Table1.a = 0. Please let me know what is wrong with this query in `MS_ACCESS`.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the exact error you got, rather than a paraphrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update Table1 
inner join Table2 
on Table1.c = Table2.d
SET Table1.a = Table2.b 
where Table1.a = 0
```

I think the syntax is a little different in Access.

This should do it